# Using attr module and metaclasses in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, metaclass, python-attrs

I am trying to use the `attr` package to simply create a metaclass with attributes and methods to use in a further class definition in Python 3. I want to use the `attrs` package since I have a lot of simple storage classes that only need a few attributes on initialization. Everything works fine, except for when I am trying to add the metaclass to the main class, the code fails with

```
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

A simple MWE would be:

```
from attr import attrs, attrib
from abc import ABCMeta

@attrs
class MetaClass(ABCMeta):

    my_attribute = attrib()

    def my_method(self):
        pass

class MyClass(object, metaclass=MetaClass):
    pass
```

For Python 2/3 compatibility I usually use the six package and the `add_metaclass` decorator therein, but I would be happy if it would work in either Python 2 or 3.

Answer (score 3):

The  `attrs` library does generate an `__init__` method for the class it is decorating. However, metaclasses have a well defined signature to `__new__` and `__init__` methods, the arguments of which are filled in by the Python runtime itself, whenever a `class` statement is executed (along with its body, that is).

I mean - it is the Python runtime that fills in the arguments "`class, name, bases, namespace`" in a call for a metaclass `__init__`, and you can't easily change that so that `class, attr1, attr2` are passed instead, as the `__init__` created by `attrs` would require.

In short, without looking further into `attrs` documentation to see if you can supress its overriding of `__init__` (and maybe some of other magic methods it creates), you can't use `attrs` with metaclasses.

For the record, Python 3.7 "dataclasses" allow one to "turn-off" the creation of an `__init__` method, but even so, metaclasses are something that have to be carefully thought of, and it is hard to think of an advanced feature for instrumenting classes that would work out of the box for metaclasses just because the language syntax allow for it.

All in all, this might be a "x,y" problem - I'd suggest not trying to use a 3rd party package with with metaclasses just because you think some of its features will play nicely there, and instead, describe what is that you want to achieve with your custom meta-classes in another question.
A few lines of code in a metaclass  `__new__` method will probably give you the wanted features, but without unknown side-effects.

In particular, if you simply want to add `my_attribute = attrib()` to all classes created with your custom metaclass, you should not try to create this in the metaclass. Perhaps, you simply need a Base superclass, and not metaclasses at all:

```py
from abc import ABC
...

@attrs
class Base(ABC):
   my_attribute = attrib()

class MyClass(Base):
   pass
```

Again, I don't know about the `attr` lib, and maybe it does not work with
inheritance (but I doubt - it should do just fine), then you could use a
metaclass to *inject the attributes* and *apply the `@attrs` decorator* on your classes, but not try to that on your metaclass itself:

```py
from attr import attrs, attrib
from abc import ABCMeta


class MetaClass(ABCMeta):

    my_attribute = attrib()

    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kw):
        cls = super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kw)
        # if the 'attrs' decorator modifies the type of "cls", 
        # the original __init__ won't be called automatically.
        # since we are inheriting from other superclass, we'd better
        # call it manually here, and suppress its automatic execution
        # bellow. 
        super(MetaClass, cls).__init__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kw)
        cls.my_attribute = attrib()
        return attrs(cls)

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kw):
        pass


class MyClass(object, metaclass=MetaClass):
    pass
```

Comment: Yes, subclassing works just fine with attrs. We've never tried subclassing metaclasses that are then used as metaclasses themselves and I'm not sure if there's a usecase for that TBH. Once you go full metaclasses like this, every expectation is out of the window.